# From which java containter I can delete elements more easily, not knowing index of element?

Tags: java, containers

Is there any java container which has two methods, add, remove, which takes only element (not index)?

I want to do something like this:

```
MagicContainer<Foo> mc = MagicContainer<Foo>();

mc.add(new Foo());
mc.add(someFoo1=new Foo());
mc.add(new Foo());
mc.add(someFoo2=new Foo());

mc.remove(someFoo1);
mc.remove(someFoo2);
```

Comment: Like the responses say, it's the java.util.Set. You have to implement equals and hashCode in the Foo class if you want to use Set.

Comment: @Victor: you **can** use `HashSet` & co without overriding `hashCode()` and `equals()` **if** the default behaviour of `Object` (i.e. each object is only equal to itself) is acceptable!

Comment: @Joachim: Yes, of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Java [`Collection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) has an [`add()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) and a [`remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method that do what you want.

Since `Collection` is an interface, you'll need to chose one of the implementations (which are usually either [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) or [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementations as well). [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a pretty common choice.

A [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is another possible candidate.

```
Colllection<Foo> mc = new ArrayList<Foo>();

mc.add(new Foo());
mc.add(someFoo1=new Foo());
mc.add(new Foo());
mc.add(someFoo2=new Foo());

mc.remove(someFoo1);
mc.remove(someFoo2);
```

Which specific implementation you want, will depend on what other properties you want.

If you want to keep a defined order and access objects by index, then you will need a `List` implementation. The "default" `List` is `ArrayList`. If you often remove/add elements anywhere *except* the end, then a `LinkedList` will provide better performance (but most of the time you won't notice the difference).

If you want to avoid duplicate objects, then you will need a `Set` implementation. The "default" `Set` is `HashSet`, but a [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is also used occasionally, providing the added benefit of having a defined order (but it requires you to either provide a [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or ensure that all elements are [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)).

Comment: as far a I know, I need to know index numer to delete something from ArrayList, so only collections which implements Set interface seems to be ok.

Comment: @noisy remove can take an object reference and is available on all list implementations.  no index is needed.

Comment: @noisy: `remove()` is actually overloaded on `List`. There's one that takes an index as an `int` and then there's the one (linked above) that takes the object to be removed (that one is inherited by the `Collection` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Any set implementation should work.

Comment: While not strictly false, this is not the whole store. The [`remove(Object)` method is defined in `Collection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29). So your `Collection` need not be a `Set` for this to be possible!